# Docker compose up --force-recreate --build uses caching but I don't want it to do so

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following command to force recreate all my containers:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build
```

However, I still see the following lines*:

```
Step 6/10 : RUN cp environment-prod-docker.js environment.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9a2354577ef
Step 7/10 : RUN cat environment.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ccbc732030ea
Step 8/10 : RUN npm ci --only=production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6baeabd30cf7
```

How can I disable that caching? (it does not rebuild my application for instance.)

I have already found, that using this specific command on the given container do re-build it:

```
 docker-compose build --no-cache
```

but for specific reasons, I need to use a one liner build'n'start command, so is there any way to produce this with `docker-compose up`?

I am using docker-compose.yml version "3.4".

*:The Dockerfile is like this:

```
...
RUN cp environment-prod-docker.js environment.js
RUN cat environment.js
RUN npm ci --only=production
...
```

Comment: Why doesn't it rebuild your application?  (Anything you `COPY` in above will invalidate the cache.)  You shouldn't routinely need `--no-cache`.

Comment: @David OP does not want the cache

Comment: I do not think there is a solution to that , if you want one liner then use `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up`

Comment: Have you removed all your individual containers images first? `docker-compose rm -f -s`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't prevent `docker-compose up` from using the build cache. The only way I've found to effectively do this is to run:

```bash
docker image rm <image>
docker builder prune
```

The first command removes the image you are rebuilding. The second command prunes dangling layers, so your next build will be fresh.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even though this command logged `Total reclaimed space: 17.59GB` which is nice, subsequent `docker-compose up` still leads to the change being used e.g. `CACHED [13/15] RUN ./script.sh`

Comment: I downvoted because I do agree, this isn't enought. `docker-compose up` still uses cached data!

Comment: @BenButterworth @AlexandreTranchant this command prunes dangling layers so you have to first `docker image rm <image>` images that you want to rebuild.

Comment: This seems to work _only_ if `--all` is passed as well.

Comment: But `docker compose build --no-cache` should work, no?

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately Marks answer doesn't work for me. However this command did:

```
docker system prune --all --force
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely overkilling (because it removes al caches for all Docker containers), but couldn't find an alternative that just forces to not use the cache for the given service that's being built.

Comment: @xarlymg89 - Agree that it's overkill. And something you want to avoid if you have a limited internet connection. The redownloading of images I was working on took over 30mins! But as you say, at present, there's no alternative with docker.

Answer (score 11):

Update: 2023-Oct

The `docker compose build`  accepts `--no-cache` option. Even though it shows [cached] in the progress, it is actually not using cache.

This is the description page https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/

Cannot comment, had to put it here. Try `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` and update your docker engine.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `docker compose up --build` still doesn't support the `--no-cache` parameter.

Another option is to add `no_cache: true` to the build definition:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#no_cache

Answer (score 1):

I want to add some point about rebuild images

```
docker-compose build --no-cache can't
```

command above  can't rebuild images in my situation. And the solution is :

```
docker build
```